# unable to redirect to another JSP page from servlet? neither using SendRedirect nor getRequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I know the similar questions have been asked before but I can not find a solution from them.

I have all my JSP files under WEB-INF and I have codes in Servlet as belows:

```
response.sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/VVmigratieeensucces.jsp");
```

The servlet has been executed.

Comment: why you want `/WEB-INF/`? just `VVmigratieeensucces.jsp` enough . BTW Did you done servlets mapping correctly?

Comment: Hi. Servlets are mapped correctly as I can see logs from the servlet.

Comment: The strange thing is that I have another servlet. It can redirect to another jsp page successfully

Comment: If it works for one file it should work for others also . i believe you might have some typo `VVmigratieeensucces.jsp` this expected to be `VVmigratieeensuccess.jsp`

Comment: There is no mistake on the jsp name. And if I remove WEB-INF, then it will cause not found issue

Comment: Yeah it's purely depends on how you configure most of them never put jsp inside web-inf .please check file names are correct look like typo some where as i mentioned earlier

Comment: WEB-INF is a special directory,invisible to the outside. Usually you place your JSP files there, if you don't want them to be called directly. So redirect is impossible. You can only forward to them. Please show your code for forwarding with RequestDispatcher. Are there any errors or exceptions? Then please post them, too.

Comment: Now I use forward but the result is the same. Can print text from Servlet. The code is like:       System.out.println("start to forward");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/VVmigratieeensucces.jsp").forward(request, response);

Comment: What exactly is the result? Are you sure you print the full stacktrace in case of an exception? What is the HTTP response in the browser (development tools)?

Comment: It is in eclipse. And I just added the part for exception. But still 'start to forward' has been printed but not forward. Also, there is no exception

Comment: This is not enough information. What is the HTTP result? It is difficult and time consuming if you don't provide all the requested infos.

Comment: What you can do for debugging: Replace your JSP with a very simple one. Include some logging to be sure the JSP is executed. In your servlet after the forward call, do some logging, too, to be sure the forward was executed normally.

Comment: The HTTP status are all 200. Should not be a problem

Comment: It looks like there is an error on the first JSP. But sure if it will cause the problem of forward via servlet to the seocnd JSP page

Comment: Hm, this is strange. And there is no content in the response? Please check this with the browser dev tools. You should further look at your JSP. see my recommendations above. You should also ensure that your servlet don't write to the response after the forward.

Comment: You are right. Vanje. I found the problem was from JSP page. On the first page, there was an error on JS.

Comment: Thank you guys for putting so much time on it.